# MySQL Delete / Inner Join performance

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

I have a MySQL database with ~27 million rows in one of its tables (analyses). I indexed two of the variables, time and ID, with the statements

```
ALTER TABLE `analyses` ADD INDEX(`time`);
ALTER TABLE `analyses` ADD INDEX(`ID`);
```

Each statement took ~4 minutes.
I then attempted to delete redundant rows, with the statement

```
DELETE a1 FROM analyses a1 INNER JOIN analyses a2 WHERE a1.log_id > a2.log_id 
AND a1.ID= a2.ID AND a1.time=a2.time;
```

This statement has been executing for ~2 days without an error.

1. Is there a way I can estimate how long this statement should take?
2. From what I understand, interrupting this process (ctrl-C or kill) would not corrupt the database; am I correct that it'd be safe to do so?
3. Is there a way I could formulate the DELETE statement to increase execution speed, or should I just wait for this process to complete?

Comment: If your MySQL version allows `EXPLAIN` on `DELETE` queries run it and post the output. Otherwise rewrite the `DELETE` query into a `SELECT` query and run a `EXPLAIN` like `EXPLAIN SELECT a1.* FROM analyses a1 INNER JOIN analyses a2 WHERE a1.log_id > a2.log_id 
AND a1.ID= a2.ID AND a1.time=a2.time;`

Comment: We also need the output off `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the query..

Comment: Also define "redundant rows".. Meaning do you want to keep the newest or latest record?  @Strawberry 's answer works for keeping the latest record within a group.. if you want to keep the newest record you need to change `MAX` into `MIN` instead.

Comment: The redundant rows are identical, so I don't care which I delete, as long as I retain one. I will cancel this command, and execute your suggestions to provide more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I canceled the original command and tried your EXPLAIN statement, I ran out of disk space; there must be a large temporary file somewhere....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just for fun, you could try creating a new table with just the records that you want to retain...

First get rid of your existing indexes, and instead create a compound index on (id,time).

Then do this...

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table AS
SELECT x.* 
  FROM analyses x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id
            , time
            , MAX(log_id) log_id
         FROM analyses
        GROUP
           BY id
            , time
      ) y
     ON y.ID = x.ID 
    AND y.time = x.time
    AND y.log_id = x.log_id;
```

Comment: @ehh a covering index `analyses(id, time, log_id)` should work even better for this query.. But if the default table engine is InnoDB and the id column is a PRIMARY/UNIQUE KEY you should add this index `analyses(time, log_id)` also and it should also executed as a covering index for this query. Because InnoDB engine stores a copy off the "primary index" within secondary indexes

Comment: @RaymondNijland Logically, log_id must be PRIMARY

Comment: "log_id must be PRIMARY" Mayby hard to say without table structures and example data? The second part off mine comment was a bit off geuss work assuming the id column is a PRIMARY KEY.. Iám sure the covering index i suggested works.

Comment: We can at least agree that id is definitely not PRIMARY !

Comment: Thanks very much, the composite index and query listed above worked.